# how to use Bootstrap theme in Django?

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Python programming and just started Django, I have a small task to use build a bootstrap blog. I have done some work with jinja templates in django. But i want to know how would i use bootstrap 3 in django because django templates work on jinja style like blocks statements and inheritance.

lot of confusion, any one here who have done this sort of work, kindly help.
also google it and found a lot of libraries, but the structure is confusing me, keep in mind that i am at beginner level.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can download the static files and copy them in your project's static library, or you can use them via CDN, that is putting in your template's header links to the Bootstrap CDN:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 5):

in django, you have [static folder](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/) which contains css, js and image folders normally.

you put bootstrap css files into css folder, js files into js folder and fonts into images.

and you link to them in template this way:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ STATIC_URL }}css/bootstrap.css">
```

or if you activated staticfiles app, then

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}">
```

the same goes for js files. just read django docs, it is the best docs ever!

Comment: I agree about Django having a documentation among the best ones in the IT / Software Development / Frameworks world

Answer (score 4):

I'll echo what the other answers have said, but for a succinct and easy to follow example see:

http://www.tangowithdjango.com/book/chapters/bootstrap.html

for a step by step instruction on how to bootstrap your django app.